# Selecting only part of the DbSet in Read method of Kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, gridview, kendo-ui

I'm trying to use a Kendo UI grid in MVC and remote data. I want to only grab and display data from the DbSet, onload, where one of the fields, "Status", equals '1'.  I thought this should be able to be accomplished in the controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    using (var db = new MyData(false))
    {
       var data = db.Training.Where(d => d.Status == '1').Select(d => new Training {
           Id = d.Id,
           Name = d.Name,
           Status = d.Status
       }).ToDataSourceResult(request);

       return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

The above code gives me the error that "The entity or complex type 'Training' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query".  Any suggestions on how to rewrite the Linq statement so it'll work, or maybe a way to do it within the grid to suppress any that do not have a Status of '1'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is trying to project to a mapped entity which is not allowed. Additionally it's redundant to do that as you already have your entities. Remember that `.Select()` is for mapping one type to another but the `.Where()` method is already returning a list of your entities (`Training`).

Remove the `.Select()` and the query should work:

```
var data = db.Training.Where(d => d.Status == '1').ToDataSourceResult(request);
```

Comment: Yep, I just discovered that, myself a min ago!  Thanks!